# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected fc1000 to have shape (30,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was trying to retrain ResNet50 model to classify given images of animals into 30 different classes. To do this, I made a list containing arrays of given images of dimension(after expanding dimensions and preprocessing it):- (1, 224, 224, 3), thereby the shape of given list(after converting it to numpy array) was (300, 1, 224, 224, 3), as initially i took only 300 images. For Ytrain, I Label encoded the classes and one hot encoded the afterwards. For 30 classes, I had an numpy array of dimension (300, 30). Then I used DataGenerator for model.fit_generator, passing Xtrain of shape (1, 224, 224, 3) and Ytrain of shape (30, ), But got the error:-

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected fc1000 to have shape (30,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Here is my code:-

```
inputShape = (224, 224)
preprocess = imagenet_utils.preprocess_input

df = pd.read_csv('DLBeginner/meta-data/train.csv')
df = df.head(300)
imagesData, target = [], []
c = 0

for images in df['Image_id']:
filename = args["target"] + '/' + images
image = load_img(filename, target_size = inputShape)
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)
image = preprocess(image)
imagesData.append(image)
c += 1
print('Count = {}, Image > {} '.format(c, images))

imagesData = np.array(imagesData)
labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
series = df['Animal'][0:300]
integerEncoded = labelEncoder.fit_transform(series)
Hot = OneHotEncoder(sparse = False)
integerEncoded = integerEncoded.reshape(len(integerEncoded), 1)
oneHot = Hot.fit_transform(integerEncoded)

model = ResNet50(include_top = True, classes = 30, weights = None)

model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

l = len(imagesData)
def DataGenerator(Xtrain, Ytrain):
while(True):
    for i in range(l):
        arr1 = Xtrain[i]
        arr2 = Ytrain[i]
        print("arr1.shape : {}".format(arr1.shape))
        print("arr2.shape : {}".format(arr2.shape))
        yield(arr1, arr2)
```

and here is the "fitting part"

```
generator = DataGenerator(imagesData, oneHot)

model.fit_generator(generator = generator, epochs = 5, steps_per_epoch=l)
```

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Switching from `'categorical_crossentropy'` to '`sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add little more details.

When you have multi-class classification problem and 
(1) if your targets are one-hot encoded then use `categorical_crossentropy`
(2) if your targets are integers as in MNIST example, use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. When you use this, Tensorflow under the hood, it will convert data into one-hot encoded and classify the data.

Hope that helps. Thanks!